# Why are there many repetitive lines saying CACHE when I render a Rails view?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

When I render a view, logs are generated that seem repetitive. The page I am rendering is a list of food. Each instance of food is a "quantity," which has a list_id and food_id.

Notice that the same line `CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]` is repeated many times. It then does the same for every subsequent food on the list.

```
Started GET "/lists/995" for ::1 at 2016-10-04 12:54:53 -0400
Processing by ListsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"995"}
  List Load (24.0ms)  SELECT  "lists".* FROM "lists" WHERE "lists"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "lists"."updated_at" DESC LIMIT 1      [["id", 995]]
  User Load (51.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id",     123]]
  Quantity Load (4.6ms)  SELECT "quantities".* FROM "quantities" WHERE "quantities"."list_id" = $1  [["list_id", 995]]
  Food Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 209045]]
  Food Load (7.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 57399]]
  Food Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 142340]]
  Food Load (17.9ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 164066]]
  Food Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 190326]]
  Food Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 118791]]
  Food Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 142341]]
  Food Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 154159]]
  Food Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 136753]]
  Food Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 159278]]
  Food Load (6.6ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 143370]]
  Food Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 211783]]
  Food Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 202338]]
  Food Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 58237]]
  Food Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 57641]]
  Food Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 212392]]
  Food Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 180967]]
  Food Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 154152]]
  Food Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  User Load (3.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 123]]
   (3.0ms)  SELECT "lists"."id" FROM "lists" WHERE "lists"."user_id" = $1  ORDER BY "lists"."updated_at" DESC  [["user_id",     123]]
   (2.2ms)  SELECT "quantities"."food_id" FROM "quantities" WHERE (list_id IN     (995,988,989,987,986,980,979,978,977,976,975,974,973,972,971,970,969,965,963,940,938,939,937,936,935,933))
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "quantities"."food_id" FROM "quantities" WHERE (list_id IN     (995,988,989,987,986,980,979,978,977,976,975,974,973,972,971,970,969,965,963,940,938,939,937,936,935,933))
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (1.8ms)  COMMIT
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (4.5ms)  UPDATE "lists" SET "total_price" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "lists"."id" = $3  [["total_price",     65.60000000000001], ["updated_at", "2016-10-04 16:54:54.823214"], ["id", 995]]
   (6.5ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered lists/_note.html.erb (9.8ms)
   (1.3ms)  SELECT "likelists"."list_id" FROM "likelists" WHERE "likelists"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 123]]
  Rendered lists/_nutrition.html.erb (6.3ms)
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered lists/_show_section_one.html.erb (32.9ms)
Scoped order and limit are ignored, it's forced to be batch order and batch size
  Quantity Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "quantities".* FROM "quantities" WHERE "quantities"."list_id" = 995 ORDER BY     "quantities"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000
  Food Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.2ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 189807]]
  Rendered lists/_item_preview_details.html.erb (17.1ms)
  Rendered lists/_items_core.html.erb (38.2ms)
  Food Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 154152]]
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 154152]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 154152]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 154152]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 154152]]
```

I'm not sure what CACHE means in this context, and I'm concerned that this apparent repetition is causing performance issues and the result of a design flaw. Please advise what I might modify to avoid this, if the repetitive logs do indeed indicate a problem in how I am rendering the page. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the code from controllers/lists_controller.rb (the show action) and views/lists/show.html.erb, please?

Comment: There is a lot of code in the views due to many partials, but ... your question guided me toward the answer! I found in one of my partials numerous database calls that were causing the extra queries. My mistake. Feel free to write an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I located numerous database calls in a view that were causing extra queries. These were redundant and should have been located in the controller. Thank you to @john-feltz for guiding me toward a solution with his comment.